# Is there a good way to pass both form information and URL parameters to server?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, query-string

In my web forms project (a forum) I have a form that is accessed through a link from another page, a link which includes parameters. for example:

```
EditPost.aspx?mid=0
```

When the page is loaded, the form hasn't yet been submitted and Request.QueryString contains the URL parameters I loaded the page with. However, after I send the form, Request.QueryString conatins the values of the form fields. This is a problem because I need the URL parameters after the form is sent.

The question is, how do i make the page send me those URL parameter with the form information?

If I'm approaching this wrong, and I'm supposed to keep the URL parameters from when the page is first loaded, let me know how.

Thanks!

Edit:

```
<form action="" id="f_editComment" name="f_editThread" method="post" onsubmit="return true;">
    <%=ThreadTitle %>
    <textarea id="body" name="body" runat="server"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: If your form appends your form elements to the query string, you're missing `method="post"` on your form. If you want it to be a GET form, then print your current URL including query string in the `action=""`.

Comment: In order for the URL parameters which initially loaded that page to be included in the form post, you'd have to include them.  Perhaps upon loading the page those parameters can be placed in hidden form fields?  Or added directly to the form action URL?  What have you tried?